# Install Python distribution or Not

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, debian-buster

I am running Debian 10 and am wondering whether it is recommended to install a python distribution on it or not. This question comes because I see that Debian 10 comes with pre-installed python 2 and python 3 plus many python modules.

Is it not wastage of system space installing extra python distributions like anaconda python or any similar python distribution on such system?

Comment: It's hard to say, without knowing what you're trying to achieve. Python 3 is fine for most projects going forward, and python 2 is good for backward compatibility. Beyond that, if you need some thing more specialized, you'll find out.

Comment: @Jason needed python for scientific work. Am a mathematician so wants python for just solving scientific equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python distributions like anaconda *mostly* exist for the convenience of ms-windows users. On ms-windows installing (compiled) python modules can be a *really* painful experience.

If you are using Debian, the built-in versions of Python *just work*. And even if a module you want is not available as a package, installation is usually pretty simple because Debian comes with most of the development tools installed or easily available.

So I would recommend to stick with the Debian supplied Python.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is it not wastage of system space installing extra python*
>   *distributions like anaconda python or any similar python distribution*
>   *on such system?*

Yes it does take extra space, but you can always get rid of the used up space by  old versions by using :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```